# Copy file which opens the app into some temp folder in the app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using my own extension ".swp" for associating files with my app. And I am able to get option of my app while user tries to open file with that extension. For e.g. If there is say file "file1.swp" anywhere in the sd card, and if user clicks on that file, my app will also be available in the options list for opening that app. But I want to save "file1.swp" in some temp folder at the time it selects my app to get opened.

Any suggestions please............

Comment: do you mean when user clicks on file1.swp file and choose to open this file with your app then file1.swp will be needed to store into temp folder

Comment: @Pratik: yes file1.swp should get stored in temp folder so that I can use that file later.

Comment: but does your application opens that file?

Comment: @pratik: not yet, when clikcked on that file, my app will get opened and user will have to click on import in order to get that file's data get populated in the listview. The reason why I want to store in temp folder is: When user clicks on import I will display alert that are you sure you want to import this file? If yes then only I will make entry of those data in database and display the contents in the listview. I hope this explanation helps...........

Comment: have you used intent-filter?

Comment: can you please share your androidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Thanks Pratik for your time, I found the way to do that. I am posting the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting my whole code below so that others having same question can refer to:

```
String strFilename = "Not set";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null)
        {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            if(uri != null)
            {
                strFilename = intent.getData().getPath();
                String NameOfFile = intent.getDataString();


                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "strFilename" + strFilename + "" + "Name of file is::" + NameOfFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("strFileName::"+ strFilename );

                System.out.println("NameOfFile::"+ NameOfFile );
                try {
                    copyFile(strFilename,"/mnt/sdcard/Profile.swp");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }else{

        }

        }





//copy file into other location
    private void copyFile(String assetFilename, String outFileName ) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("outFileName ::" + outFileName);
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(assetFilename);

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

Comment: It's gud that you found the answer:)